# How to automatically change the "rad" mode to "deg" mode on google calculator when searching an equation?

Tags: google-search, google-calculator

So, I know that there is a button to change "rad" to "deg" on the google calculator, but it is not what I meant.

You can write your equation directly on the search bar and then get a result, however, google doesn't change to that mode no matter what I write.

[image: Screenshot of the search bar equation showing the "rad" mode]